# Electron.js app freezes after an hour unused

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, vuetify.js

I wrote an app with electron.js and vuetify.js for Windows 64bit; everything is ok about the app and its usual use case. The problem is: when the app is running and the user doesn't do anything with it, I mean leave it running (app main window is open) without any other processing, after about 1 hour, when the user tries to work with the program, the program hangs up and does not work, and the user is forced to close and reopen the program.

The same problem happens when the user runs the program and takes Windows to Hibernate mode, and after the restart of Windows, the program does not respond and and does not work.

- electron version : 3.0.0

**Solution:**

the problem was solved with just one line code in the background.js file of electron, the problem came from **Hardware Acceleration** and because of that the app use more resources and and some hours make app not respond

```
app.disableHardwareAcceleration();
```

by adding above code in the background process file the app runs and work very fast

Comment: Please read the [help] before posting.

Comment: It is likely due to a problem with the app, not Electron. Try profiling it, maybe there is a memory leak or an infinite loop, although it might be just a bug

Comment: @ᆼᆺᆼ , I also thought that there was a problem with the program
But for myself, no problem occurs on my computer, and on the other hand, the high consumption of RAM is common with chromium inside electron.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a memory leak. Without more information though it's tough to resolve, but you could start here :

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: Thank you to post your answer, that's point you mentioned is very important but for my problem this not the real solution and no memory leaks was there! I was updated my question post and add the solution the problem came from Hardware Acceleration